# FileSystemWatcher in docker container watching file share on windows

Tags: c#, .net, linux, docker, filesystemwatcher

I am using a service in .net 5.o which is run on a linux docker container. The app uses a FileSystemWatcher to watch for files on a windows file share

the file share is stored in appSettings.json and works fine when I run from windows. T

> "\\\\fileshare\\files"

How do I specify this path so it will work in my Linux container?

I have tried this with no joy in appsettings

> "file:///\\\\fileshare\\archives"

```cs
var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
{
    Path = folder,
    NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                            | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName,
    Filter = $"*.txt",
    IncludeSubdirectories = false
};
```